# unity game engine, sphinx and google speech api on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-api, speech

i am trying to build a game with unity which have Arabic speech recognition to be used on android devices. I am stuck at the speech recognition tool. which one is more suitable with unity ? can i use google API directly ? if yes can i control the data ?

or sphinx is more suitable for game on android device ? I have read about sphinx but the acoustic model of Arabic language was not available but for it.

I have tried to make it using MATLAB but it will cost me a lot to build it on mobile using MATLAB coder and also it does not have all the required libraries.

any help about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official unity plugin for pocketsphinx is here:

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-unity-demo

Arabic model has to be trained, yes. In the end you could have a good system, but you have to invest enough into it.

Comment: the provided link is for OSX not for android.